# Create column with a certain week value by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a column, by group, with a certain week's value from another column.

In this example New_column is created with the Number from the 2nd week for each group.

```
Group  Week  Number   New_column
 A      1      19         8
 A      2       8         8
 A      3      21         8
 A      4       5         8

 B      1       4        12
 B      2      12        12
 B      3      18        12
 B      4      15        12

 C      1       9         4
 C      2       4         4
 C      3      10         4
 C      4       2         4
```

I've used this method, which works, but I feel is a really messy way to do it:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(New_column = ifelse(Week == 2, Number, NA))

df <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(New_column = sum(New_column, na.rm = T))
```

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(New_column = Number[Week == 2])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several solution possible, depending on what you need specifically. With your specific sample data, however, all of them give the same result

---

1) It identifies the week number from column `Week`, even if the dataframe is not sorted

```
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(New_column = Number[Week == 2])
```

However, if the weeks do not start from 1, this solution will still try to find the case only where `Week == 2`

---

2) If `df` is already sorted by `Week` inside each group, you could use

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(New_column = Number[2])
```

This solution does not take the week `Number` in which `Week == 2`, but rather the second week within each group, regardless of its actual `Week` value.

---

3) If `df` is not sorted by week, you could do it with

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  arrange(Week, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(New_column = Number[2])
```

and uses the same rationale as solution 2)

Comment: Thank you @Ric ! For my specific case the third way did the trick